# In iOS Maps Embed API after click "view larger map" cannot return to the app

Tags: ios, cordova, dictionary, ionic-framework, iframe

I embedded a google map in an ionic 3 app. When I click the "view larger map" link, map open in a full page but has no way to go back to the original app. This only happen in iOS platform, works fine in Android.  How to open the "larger map" in a new browser window after click "view larger map" link in iOS iframe? Thanks for any help!

Comment: In my case this happens only when the device doesn't have google map installed. Any update on this?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this as well. As above, this works fine on Android. Suspect it might have something to do with the target="_blank" instead of "_system", but since this is an iframe you have no access. Can't see any way to remove the link, so the only solution is to either (a) not have the map on iphone or (b) don't use the embed option and get hit with the quota. Either option is not optimal. Maybe if you cleverly overlayed the existing link with an anchor with a target of "_system" outside of the iframe in the same spot and crossed your fingers that the layout didn't change :-)